# BxSlider destroySlider() function not working: slider undefined or is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have a bunch of posts displayed in a carousel using bxslider. The code that fires the carousel looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var carouselWidth = 640;
var carousel;
var carousel_Config = {
          minSlides: 1,
          maxSlides: 5,
          slideWidth: 285,
          slideMargin: 25,
          controls: false,
          pagerSelector: '.pager'
}

    if( jQuery(window).width() > carouselWidth) {
        carousel = jQuery('.event-carousel').bxSlider(carousel_Config);
    };

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        if( jQuery(window).width() > carouselWidth) {
            carousel = jQuery('.event-carousel').bxSlider(ttCarousel_Config);
        } else {
            carousel.destroySlider();
        }
    });

});
```

Easy, right?

Problem is that destroySlider() does not work: I get that "carousel" is undefined. It's the same if I try with:

```
jQuery('.event-carousel').bxSlider().destroySlider();
```

I tried to declare "carousel" outside the jQuery(document...) putting var carousel; at top of the script but I always get the same result in console: Carousel is undefined.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is carousel is getting created/initialized properly on page?

Comment: Yes, it's created properly on first page load and if I resize the window to more than 640px. However, if I shrink it back under 640px i get "carousel is undefined" and cannot get destroySlider() to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try with below code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var carouselWidth = 640;
var carousel = null;
var carousel_Config = {
          minSlides: 1,
          maxSlides: 5,
          slideWidth: 285,
          slideMargin: 25,
          controls: false,
          pagerSelector: '.pager'
}

    if( jQuery(window).width() > carouselWidth) {
        if(carousel == null)
            carousel = jQuery('.event-carousel').bxSlider(carousel_Config);
    };

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        if( jQuery(window).width() > carouselWidth) {
            if(carousel == null)
                carousel = jQuery('.event-carousel').bxSlider(ttCarousel_Config);
            else
                carousel.reloadSlider(); //reloading the slider if already instance present
        } else {
            if(carousel){
                carousel.destroySlider();
                carousel = null;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Please check `carousel` object before destroying it. Same applies for initializing the `carousel`. If its already there then no need to create/re-init the carousel.

Comment: Small improvement: I had just to change the window.resize part using .reloadSlider() in this way: `jQuery(window).resize(function() {
   if( jQuery(window).width() > carouselWidth) {
    if(ttCarousel) {
      ttCarousel.reloadSlider();
    }
   } else {
    if(ttCarousel) {
     ttCarousel.destroySlider();
    }
   }
  });`
Otherwise the slider doesn't re-apply css rules relative to media queries, if present, so it may led to wrong appearence

Comment: oh ok. but i guess you still need `else` statement like `jQuery(window).resize(function() { if( jQuery(window).width() > carouselWidth) { if(ttCarousel) { ttCarousel.reloadSlider(); } else{ ttCarousel = jQuery('.event-carousel').bxSlider(ttCarousel_Config); } } else { if(ttCarousel) { ttCarousel.destroySlider(); } } });`

Comment: Yeah, I was just adding your same answer :) Could you please update the above answer with the latest code for future reference?